# How do I connect to a remote Parity node from web3.js?

Tags: web3js, json-rpc, parity, aws

I’ve installed parity on a AWS EC2 instance following these [instructions](http://ethereum-alarm-clock-service.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html#setup-an-ec2-instance) and started parity with the `--jsonrpc-apis 'web3,eth,net,parity'` flag. I've also tried many other flags, such as `--rpccorsdomain '*'`

However I’m struggling to connect to it using web3.js.

Also I’ve, temporarily, opened all inbound traffic from my IP

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the JSONRPC docs:

```
--jsonrpc-port PORT          Specify the port portion of the JSONRPC API server
                             (default: 8545).
--jsonrpc-interface IP       Specify the hostname portion of the JSONRPC API
                             server, IP should be an interface's IP address, or
                             all (all interfaces) or local (default: local).
--jsonrpc-cors URL           Specify CORS header for JSON-RPC API responses.
                             (default: None)
--jsonrpc-apis APIS          Specify the APIs available through the JSONRPC
                             interface. APIS is a comma-delimited list of API
                             name. Possible name are web3, eth, net, personal,
                             parity, parity_set, traces, rpc, parity_accounts.
                             (default: web3,eth,net,parity,traces,rpc).
--jsonrpc-hosts HOSTS        List of allowed Host header values. This option will
                             validate the Host header sent by the browser, it
                             is additional security against some attack
                             vectors. Special options: "all", "none",
                             (default: none).
```

So, enabling the required APIs as you did is only one piece of the puzzle you are trying to solve :)

Assuming you are fine with default port and default APIs, let's have a look at the following features you probably want:

- `--jsonrpc-interface all` enables the HTTP JSON-RPC API on all network interfaces, not only the local loop-back. You could also specify `--jsonrpc-interface 133.33.33.37` which your public IP to only serve RPC to the public network interface.

Give this a try, it should work already, assuming you have opened the RPC port against the AWS firewall. Additional fine-tuning can be achieved via

- `--jsonrpc-hosts all` to allow all host header values sent by the browser.
- `--jsonrpc-cors '*'` to allow all CORS requests from any domain.

Note, you probably want to disable sensible APIs such as `personal,parity_accounts,parity_set` and also disable other features such as `--no-ui`, `--no-dapps`, `--no-secretstore`, `--no-code`, or `--no-storage` to harden your client.

Answer (score 2):

+1 @Vlal. Along with `--jsonrpc-hosts all --jsonrpc-interface all` I had to add `--jsonrpc-cors null` instead of `--rpccorsdomain "*"`

Answer (score 1):

the short version (if you're on a trusted network and assuming you don't have any local firewalls running):

`--jsonrpc-hosts all --jsonrpc-interface all`

then you connect via (and change the IP obviously): 
   `web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8545"));`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
jsonrpc-cors all
```

AND

```
jsonrpc-hosts all
```

either directly in the command (`--jsonrpc-cors all --jsonrpc-hosts all`) or in the `.toml` config file.